# I find that there always a wavy line in the URL before people's name in its profile web page.What is the significance of it?

Tags: url, web

I find that there always a wavy line in the URL before people's name in its profile web page.Such as this webpage:http://cg.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/people/~taochen/

There is a '~' before name 'taochen'.

What is the significance of it?A rule or a habit?

Comment: Look at [why vim uses hjkl](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/why-vim-uses-hjkl-as-arrow-keys/) and then look at the upper right most key on that keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tilde (~) often indicates a users home directory (in the Unix world).  So when an educational institution wants to signify webpages that are generated in more or less non-controlled ways, a tilde is a good way to tell the open Internet, "hey, this website is the creation of someone that doesn't own this whole domain".  Or, "this is their *home* webpage".

And to answer part two... it is a best practice, not a rule.